IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> equivalent in .net 8 isolated version
I have an Angular app which calls this Azure Function app.
With .NET 6.0 in-process, this code is working fine and sending messages using SignalR:
[FunctionName("SendMessage")]
public static async Task<ActionResult<bool>> SendMessage(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequest message,
        [SignalR(HubName = HubName)] IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages, ILogger logger)
{
    try
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Companion SendMessage Successfully Started");

        string requestBody = new StreamReader(message.Body).ReadToEnd();

        logger.LogInformation("Companion SendMessage Request Body {0}", requestBody);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestBody))
        {
            logger.LogInformation("Companion Functionapp SendMessage : Request Body Empty");
            return new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a payload to broadcast in the request body.");
        }

        var deserializedMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageDetails>(requestBody);

        logger.LogInformation("Companion SendMessage Message Details", deserializedMessage);

        await signalRMessages.AddAsync(
                new SignalRMessage
                {
                    UserId = deserializedMessage.ClientId,
                    Target = deserializedMessage.Method,
                    Arguments = new[] { deserializedMessage }
                });

        logger.LogInformation("Companion SendMessage Completed");

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogError(ex, "Companion SendMessage : An exception has occurred while processing the SignalR messages {0}", ex);
        throw;
    }
}

Documentations are not clear on this
https://github.com/Log234/azure-functions-signalr-dotnet-isolated-demo/issues/3
What would be the equivalent signature in .NET 8.0 isolated process?
    [FunctionName("SendMessage")]
    public static async Task<ActionResult<bool>> SendMessage(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequest message,
        [SignalR(HubName = HubName)] IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages, ILogger logger)

